# Alamofire.requestObject custom case not invoking

Tags: ios, json, swift, mapping, alamofire

As a lot of people has this error, so do I, I have no idea why the "responseObject cannot be invoked with argument list of type ((JSONResponse>) -> _)"

I'm also using mapping for JSON with Alamofire+ObjectMapper

Do anybody have an idea, whats wrong with Alamofire, its very often error, may be any thoughts about understanding Alamofire?

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import AlamofireObjectMapper
import ObjectMapper

public protocol Mappable {
    static func newInstance(map: Map) -> Mappable?
    mutating func mapping(map: Map)
}

class JMapping {



    func getJSON() {

        let url = "http://www.somestringToJson/json.json"


        Alamofire
        .request(.GET, url, parameters: nil)


            .responseObject { (response: JSONResponse?) in
                println(response?.title)
                if let events = response?.events {
                    for event in events {
                        println(event.id)
                        println(event.title)

                    }
                }
        }
    }

}




class JSONResponse: Mappable {
    var title: String?
    var id: String?
    var events: [EventsResponse]?


    class func newInstance(map: Map) -> Mappable? {
            return JSONResponse()
        }


    func mapping(map: Map) {
        title <- map["title"]
        id <- map["id"]
        events <- map["events"]

    }


}

class EventsResponse: Mappable {
    var title: String?
    var id: String?
    var content: [ContentResponse]?

    class func newInstance(map:Map) -> Mappable? {
        return EventsResponse()
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        title <- map["title"]
        id <- map["id"]
        content <- map["content"]
    }

}

class ContentResponse: Mappable{
    var content_type: String?
    var visible: Bool?
    var data: NSArray?

    class func newInstance(map: Map) -> Mappable? {
        return ContentResponse()
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        content_type <- map["content_type"]
        visible <- map["visible"]
        data <- map["data"]
    }
}
```

Comment: actually  `.responseObject { (response: JSONResponse?, error: NSError?) in....`

Not working too

Comment: And I tried this `.responseObject { (_, response: JSONResponse?, _, error: NSError?) in` as well

Answer (score 0):

```
            Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://yoururl.de")
                    .response { (request, response, data, error) in

                    }
```

Basic alamofire get request looks like this. Response is called when request is finished.
After that I would recommend to use SwiftyJSON and convert your responsed data.

```
    if let data = (responseBody as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        let json = JSON(data: data)
        println(json)
    }
```

Comment: not actually response, but responseObject, anyway no luck